The composer.lock file is different on the server and local
I'm working on a laravel project.
I have copied all files including composer.json and composer.lock files from the GitLab repository.
Then I run the below command to install all packages and their dependencies:
composer install

Now all packages are installed, and my project works properly on the local.
But when I want to push new changes to the remote repository I have found that while composer.json on the local and server are identical but composer.lock files are different.
The image below shows a small part of these differences:

Now I am worried that if I put the changes on the production version, the whole project will have problems.
What is the reason for the difference in composer.lock files?

install does not modify an existing lockfile if it's up-to-date. It reads your lockfile. If your lockfile is different from what you got originally from the repository, it means you performed some other operation (like update or requireing some other package... in which case it makes sense the lockfile is different now, since your dependencies have changed)

@yivi, I think I ran the composer update command once by mistake. However, to avoid the error, I once again got the composer.json file from git and deleted the composer.lock file, and then run the composer install command, hoping to solve this problem, but the differences remain.

Again, install does not modify your existing lockfile. If you delete it, it’s the same as running update.

Take the composer.lock from git and run install.

This might have something to do with your deployment process. What exactly are you doing? Make sure you checkout your project (incl. the existing lock file) in production before running composer install

@Olivier, I do that but now I got this error: Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update. while both composer.json and composer.lock files are identical to their  server versions

Then you have a completely different problem. You pushed a lockfile in a wrong state to the repository. That's actually unrelated to this question, that's simply: your repo is messed up, you need to clean up your dependencies, run tests, and commit and push fixed up versions.

You may have a PHP version incompatible with the package versions listed in your lock file.

The install command does not modify an existing lockfile if it's up-to-date.
It reads your lockfile. If your lockfile is different from what you got originally from the repository, it means you performed some other operation (like update or requireing some other package... in which case it makes sense the lockfile is different now, since your dependencies have changed).
The lockfile will be different from what you got from the repo in three cases:

You ran update
You required or removed a package.
You deleted the lockfile, and ran install again: this is the same as running update, since composer cannot figure out a locked state for the dependencies, it will just have to create a new lockfile from scratch, getting the latest dependencies.

If you modified your lockfile unintentionally and don't want to push a different lockfile upstream, simply restore the changes to your composer.* files to the latest known-good commit you got from the repository.
